# Why is the button not centered?

Tags: html, css

I thought adding a `margin` of `auto` on an element with a known `width` will center an element because margins on both sides will become equal. However, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong: how can I center this button on the page?

```css
     p {
           font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
           font-size: 18px;
       }
       
       button {
           background-color: lightblue;
           color: white;
           padding: 15px 32px;
           border-radius: 4px;
           border: 5px solid lightblue;
           
       }
       
       .upload-button {
           width: 300px;
           margin: 10px auto;
   
       }
       
       button:hover {
           background: white;
           border: 5px solid lightblue;
           color: lightblue;
       }
       
       html, body {
           height: 100%;
       }
       
       body {
           width: 960px;
           margin: auto;
       }
```

```html
<button id="upload-button" class="upload-button" type="button">why is this button not centered</button>
```

Comment: Do you want it to be centered only horizontally or both horizontally and vertically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A button is an inline element by default, so you can center it by adding a container `div` around the button and give that container a `text-align: center` property to align the button correctly.

```css
#container {
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <button>Centered button!</button>
</div>
```

The `margin: 0 auto` only works when your element is a block-level element. So you could also add `display: block` to your button to achieve the same thing. Although this would give the button a full-width (100%) by default, so you would need to give it a fixed with too.

```css
#button1 {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Centered button!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, duncan. You're correct. However, how come it doesn't center without the div and text-align center. I only ask because the body has a defined with 960px and the button is 300px so shouldn't a margin of auto on the button center it?

Comment: Awesome! I did not know margin auto only works on block-level elements.. I will accept the answer in 6 minutes when SO lets me :)

Comment: @GovindRai Happy to help :) I've added some examples too

Comment: @DuncanLuk Thank you so much sir. Your answer solved my problem.